# Jquery Closest can not catch form data individually return undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form in a loop, I have to catch this form data individually and action something. But I can not catch the submitted data with jquery closest. Please anyone help me by correcting the portion of the following code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".add").on("click", function () {
            var v = $(this).closest("division").find("input[name=’roll’]").val();
            alert(v);
        });
    });
</script>
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    echo'<div class = "division">'
    . '<form method="POST" action="">'
    . '<p><input type="number" name="roll" placeholder="Enter Roll"></p>'
    . '<p><input type="submit" name = "submit" value = "Click"></p>'
    . '</form></div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Your Code with this,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".add").on("click", function () {
            var v = $(this).closest(".division").find("input[name='roll']").val();
            alert(v);
        });
    });
</script>
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    echo'<div class = "division">'
        . '<form method="POST" action="">'
        . '<p><input type="number" name="roll" placeholder="Enter Roll"></p>'
        . '<p><input type="button" class="add" name = "submit" value = "Click"></p>'
        . '</form></div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add "." while refers a class in jquery, replace you code. Also closest refers parent tag, and i can't see any element with **add** class in the form.

```
var v = $(this).closest(".division").find("input[name=’roll’]").val();
```

Comment: Thanks, found the problem and added .add class.